# How to center a shape so it is "visually" centered in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, optical-illusion

Say I have 65,000+ shapes (i.e. the CJK Unicode Characters as vector glyphs). I want to create a square for each of the characters and place each vector glyph within its square **such that it is *visually* centered**. Not **technically centered**, but **visually centered**. Optically centered (i.e. [optical adjustment](https://medium.muz.li/optical-effects-9fca82b4cd9a)). Is there an "align to optical center vertically and horizontally" button in Illustrator? Or if not, how would I go about doing this? I assume it's a complicated algorithm that can be used to solve this problem, but I'm not sure if it's been implemented or done in Illustrator before.

Maybe it's an Illustrator plugin somewhere. If so, it would help to know how to do it there.

Comment: Relevant: ["With optical kerning, the program uses an algorithm to calculate, from their outlines, the optimal spacing for each pair of consecutive characters."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning#Automatic_and_manual_kerning) Indesign does offer optical kerning so there are probably way to try and automate optical boundaries. However, it is far from perfect in my experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Unfortunately NO as far as I know!**

> I want to create a square for each of the characters and place each vector glyph within its square such that it is visually centered. Not technically centered, but visually centered.!

- you are totally mixing *two different things* here. The one you've read from article is mainly used while designing the interface (i.e. Human Interface/UI/UX) so it's totally good for going with visually balanced versions of assets rather than technically/geometrically balanced because those assets are completely being designed for ***Humans and their Eyes***. While,finding an option to placing them as visually balanced in any digital tool are seems impossible and possibly illogical because....
- Remember any software follows physics and maths from the core so the illustrator might able to distinguish physical boundaries but there is no clear value as **"Optical Boundaries"** at all!!
- Developer need a logic to make any functions and it's clear than there is no official formula to calculate optical balance among object so developer can't make that feature at all.
- And not but least **Optical Balance** is partially/totally unbalanced value because for one person's eye something might be optically balanced but for another people it might not!

**TLDR:** Sorry, There can't be any **AUTOMATIC** way to balance objects **VISUALLY**!